# Play animation backwards

Tags: xamarin, lottie

I added click event on my AnimationView and I'm trying to play the animation with the first click and play the animation backwards with the second one.

Which would be the best way to achieve it?

Com.Airbnb.Xamarin.Forms.Lottie 4.1.0
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2291

Comment: Try [setting speed to -1](https://github.com/Baseflow/LottieXamarin/blob/develop/Lottie.Forms/AnimationView.cs#L166) to reverse the animation. From there, you'll need to show us what you've tried to receive help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew suggested, the trick was to play with positive/negative animation speed.

```
if (!animationShowing)
{
   this.menuView.Speed = 3;
   this.menuView.PlayMinAndMaxFrame(0, 20);
}

else
{
   this.menuView.Speed = -3;
   this.menuView.PlayAnimation();
}
```